# c# version 8 Target-typed new-expressions error requires (), [], or {} after type

Tags: c#, .net-core, .net-core-3.1, c#-8.0

I'm following a tutorial to learn the new features of c# version 8 using .Net Core 3.1

I'm working with latest version of Visual Studio 2019.
while playing with some exercises i fond errors in the next code

Subject: **Target-typed new-expressions**

```
Dictionary<string, List<int>> field = new Dictionary<string, List<int>>();
Dictionary<string, List<int>> field = new(); //this throws the error "requires (), [], or {} after type requires (), [], or {} after type"
```

did i miss something?
i also tried to add to the project

```
<LangVersion>8.0</LangVersion>
```

any ideas?

Comment: Don't you still need `new Dictionary<string, List<int>>()`? Is there link to a  new feature where this is no longer required?

Comment: yes, there are a few:

https://www.infoq.com/news/2019/01/c-sharp-targeted-type-new/

Comment: link2  https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/c-sharp-8-x-next/

Comment: link 3 https://dzone.com/articles/c-80-is-here

Comment: also in a book:  https://subscription.packtpub.com/book/application_development/9781788296229/11/ch11lvl1sec83/target-typed-new-expressions

Comment: Doesn’t seem to be done yet - https://github.com/dotnet/csharplang/blob/master/proposals/target-typed-new.md

Comment: I see, could it be working in the preview version of  .net core 5?

https://dotnet.microsoft.com/download/dotnet/5.0

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The syntax you are using is not valid, despite what you may find in any online tutorials. Target-typed `new` was originally planned for C# 8.0 but didn't end up making the final cut.

It is now (2020-05-10) marked with a milestone of "9.0 *Candidate*", meaning it's *possible* it won't be part of the next iteration either. See [this github proposal/issue](https://github.com/dotnet/csharplang/issues/100).

That being said, you can try the feature out on [SharpLab](https://sharplab.io/#v2:EYLgZgpghgLgrgJwgZwLQygg5hG6CeADhACaoB2EA7gDQwgCWANgD4ACADAARsCMALAG4AsACg2AZh4AmLgGEuAbzFdVPKW35cAsgAoAlEpVqTAEQYBjGAwD25TPgA8DcjBpcXMAHxcAHlwBeLkoqAxFREwBfMUigA==) by selecting the "C# Next: Target-typed new (9 Mar 2020)" branch.